# Rails params encoding with Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I'm running an app (on Dreamhost) that works fine in the development environment, but does not work properly in production.  I've tried eliminating every difference I could: using the same mysql instance, for example.

The only thing I can see is that my query params seem to be encoded strangely.

Here's how they look in the development instance:

This search:

```
GET "/individuals?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search%5Bfirstname_like%5D=&search%5Blastname_like%5D=jones&commit=Search"
```

Produces these params:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>{"firstname_like"=>"", "lastname_like"=>"jones"}, "commit"=>"Search"}
```

In the production instance:

```
GET "/individuals/?utf8=%25E2%259C%2593&search%255Bfirstname_like%255D=&search%255Blastname_like%255D=jones&commit=Search"
```

Produces these params:

```
Parameters: {"commit"=>"Search", "search%5Bfirstname_like%5D"=>"", "utf8"=>"%E2%9C%93", "search%5Blastname_like%5D"=>"jones"}
```

The query string seems to have an extra "25" in there.

Any idea what gives?

Comment: Looks like they're double encoded for some reason. Might want to compare the versions of the gems you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an Apache "mod_rewrite" issue.  I had a .htaccess file from [html5boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com) that was causing the problem.